# Unkown maxMessageLength-attribute in asp.ent

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, httpruntime

I have a small problem with asp.net web.config. If i try to configurate the `maxMessageLength` for soap requests, i get the following error message:

> Unkown maxMessageLength-attribute....

This is my configuration in the `system.web` section:

```
<httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600" executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
```

This are the current .Net framework information: *Microsoft .NET Framework-Version:2.0.50727.8637; ASP.NET-Version:2.0.50727.7046*.

What am i doing wrong? I don't have access to the iis or windows server, because the site is hosted on a limited account.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no such attributes on `httpRuntime`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.80%29.aspx What are you need them for? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to send large xml-strings to a WebMethod.